# how to access data from json converted from xml nodejs api

Tags: node.js, json, xml, api

I have developed nodejs api which accepts xml as input, I was able to access it in the nodejs and convert the xml to below mentioned json.

```
var data   = {
       "ns0:service1":{  
          "$":{  
             "xmlns:ns0":"http://www.google.com"
          },
          "ns0:messageheader":{  
             "$":{  
                "version":"1.0",
                "xmlns:ns1":"http://www.google.com/logo"
             },
             "ns1:sourcesystemcode":"MUST",
             
             "ns1:operation":"Process",
             "ns1:targetsystemlist":{  
                "ns1:targetsystemcode":"TEST1",
                "ns1:targetsystemname":"TEST1"
             }
          },
          "ns0:messagedata":{  
             "ns3:messagedata":{  
                "$":{  
                   "xmlns:ns3":"http://www.google.com/logo2"
                },
                "ns3:somessagerequestdata":{  
                   "ns3:sorequestorderheader":{  
                      "ns3:sourcecode":"TEST1",
                      "ns3:msgdate":"2014-05-28T11:48:31",
                         "ns3:deliveryaddress":{  
                         "ns3:name":"John",
                         "ns3:streetname":"Latin",
                         "ns3:housenumber":"53"
                      },
                      "ns3:customeraddress":"",
                      "ns3:sorequestline":{  
                         "ns3:orderid":"ord_001",
                         "ns3:linetype":"testing",
                         "ns3:itemnumber":"001",
                         "ns3:itemdescription":"iphonex",
                         "ns3:quantity":"1",
                         
                      }
                   }
                }
             }
          }
       }
    }
```

how can i access the values like "ord_001" "testing" "001" "iphonex"  "1" in node js.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use bracket notation:

```
data["ns0:service1"]["ns0:messagedata"]["ns3:messagedata"]["ns3:somessagerequestdata"]["ns3:sorequestorderheader"]["ns3:sorequestline"]["ns3:orderid"] will get you to ord_001.

data["ns0:service1"]["ns0:messagedata"]["ns3:messagedata"]["ns3:somessagerequestdata"]["ns3:sorequestorderheader"]["ns3:sorequestline"] will get you to the whole object you're looking for.
```

The way those objects are set up is pretty rough though. Something is blocking JSON.parse(data) from working.